# What do I do if my package isn't being detected?

Tags: python

I am on Windows. If I run a piece of Python code including `import manim`, the following error message appears.

> RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
> warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)

However, I have installed ffmpeg via pip. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What should I do?*

Install [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) rather than [ffmpeg python package](https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg/). It is quite popular so you should be able to find tutorial relevant for your operating system, search for *How to install FFmpeg (your operating system name here)* or similar.

Comment: It worked for me with your advise, I found the steps on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/